# Does memcache need to be started as a daemon separately when used with django?

Tags: python, django, memcached, django-settings, python-memcached

I am trying to integrate caching with my django project. After some research I am convinced `memcache` is best for this. So, I require to install memcache through `apt-get memcache` and then its python bindings again as another `apt-get python-memcache`. Then, I need to include in `settings.py`:

```
CACHES = {
    'default':{
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1;11211',
    }

}
```

My question is, all the tutorials follow upto this step. Is the above enough for setting up the cache? Do I need to do something to start `memcache` when running the project? If so, can I start memcache with `python manage.py runserver` command?

Comment: Similarly to redis, postresql and so on - yes, of course you have to start it separately from django app. Django can connect to either of them.

Comment: How can I start it with django server?